# report to show all my outstanding activity

Tags: civireport, reports

I want to be able to pull a report that shows all the activity that i have recorded, for scheduled, completed and ongoing.
How do i do this please?

Answer (score 1):

You could base the report on the standard Activity report which can be found at Reports>All Reports>Activity Details.

If you are not too familiar with how reports and report templates work check this chapter of the User Guide: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/reporting/what-is-civireport/